# Query parsing in ANTLR for Lucene

Tags: java, lucene, antlr, antlr3

Probably it will combine several questions, but the context is the same.

**Background**: I need to implement custom query parsing for Lucene. The reason is that i dont store some fields in Lucene, but just keep them in a separate db, because they are changing too often. This field is classification category, i.e. *cat*

So, I want to parse the query like this:

> (cat:important and hello) or (cat:not_important and hi)

Are there any standard ANTLR4 query parsers (or examples) for Lucene like language?
Is there a way to introduce custom QueryNode without need for me to rewrite everything (Sytax, QueryBuilders, and etc.) from scratch?

Thanks a lot folks!!!

Comment: Your first question is a "no", which implies that your second is also a "no" (if I understand it correctly...).

Comment: why are u so sure about the 2nd, one is independent from the other!

Comment: ah, okay, then I misunderstood it. I thought your second question was only relevant if there actually was a ANTLR4 query parser  that you could use and would let you introduce some custom nodes to.

Comment: no, no ;) on the contrary, if option b works, its even better - less code to write

Comment: Ah, wait, I see `QueryNode` is an existing Lucene class. I thought `QueryNode` was just a generic AST-node in terms of parsing... I only know a bit of ANTLR, you'll have to wait for someone knowledgeable in Lucene to help you, sorry.

Comment: Its ok, thank you very much anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

I would even:

1. modify the original [StandardQueryParser.jj](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/queryparser/src/java/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/flexible/standard/parser/StandardSyntaxParser.jj) file, generating another `QueryParser` with the help of [JavaCC](https://javacc.java.net/) (which generates LL descent parsers just like AntLR),
2. translate the original [StandardQueryParser.jj](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/queryparser/src/java/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/flexible/standard/parser/StandardSyntaxParser.jj) file to the correct AntLR grammar syntax, or
3. check if `ExtendableQueryParser` isn't enough for that kind of fields.